# send and receive audio between android and java server using socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to send audio to java server from android.
and stream audio received from another android client
using below code.

for android client:

```
    package com.kosarsoft.translator.activity;

    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.media.AudioFormat;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.AudioRecord;
    import android.media.AudioTrack;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.kosarsoft.classes.entity.tabs;
    import com.kosarsoft.presenter.main.MainContract;
    import com.kosarsoft.presenter.main.MainPresenterImpl;
    import com.kosarsoft.translator.R;
    import com.kosarsoft.translator.component.ButtonView;
    import com.kosarsoft.translator.component.TextBlock;
    import com.kosarsoft.translator.servers.MediaStreamClient;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.DatagramPacket;
    import java.net.DatagramSocket;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.List;

    import butterknife.BindView;
    import butterknife.ButterKnife;
    import butterknife.OnClick;
    import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

    import static com.kosarsoft.classes.Constant.USER_TYPE;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainContract.View {
        private MainContract.Presenter presenter;

        @BindView(R.id.rcvConferences)
        RecyclerView rcvConferences;

        @BindView(R.id.btnRightSlideMenu)
        ImageView btnRightSlideMenu;

        @BindView(R.id.drawer_layout)
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

        @BindView(R.id.right_drawer)
        LinearLayout right_drawer;

        @BindView(R.id.lstMenu)
        ListView lstMenu;

        @BindView(R.id.btnStart)
        ButtonView btnStart;

        @BindView(R.id.btnStop)
        ButtonView btnStop;

        @BindView(R.id.btnListen)
        ButtonView btnListen;


        public byte[] buffer;
        public static DatagramSocket socket;
        private String ip = "192.168.1.9";
        private int port = 50005;

        AudioRecord recorder;

        private int sampleRate = 16000; // 44100 for music
        private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
        private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
        private boolean status = true;


        static final int frequency = 44100;
        static final int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
        static final int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;


        private boolean r_status = true;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            presenter = new MainPresenterImpl(this, MainActivity.this);

            presenter.getMenu();

            if (USER_TYPE == 5) {
                btnStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnListen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                btnStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnListen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            AudioManager mAudioMgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mAudioMgr.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);
        }

        @OnClick({R.id.btnRightSlideMenu, R.id.btnStart, R.id.btnStop, R.id.btnListen})
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnRightSlideMenu:
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(right_drawer);
                    break;
                case R.id.btnStart:
                    status = true;
                    startStreaming();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnStop:
                    status = false;
                    recorder.release();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnListen:
                    //new MediaStreamClient(MainActivity.this, ip, 8072);
                    startReceiving();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void startStreaming() {


            Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                        Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                        Log.d("VS", "Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                        DatagramPacket packet;

                        final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                        Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");

                        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, minBufSize * 10);
                        Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                        recorder.startRecording();


                        while (status == true) {


                            //reading data from MIC into buffer
                            minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                            //putting buffer in the packet
                            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, destination, port);

                            socket.send(packet);
                            System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " + minBufSize);


                        }


                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                    }
                }

            });
            streamThread.start();
        }

        public void startReceiving() {
            Thread r_Thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputStream is = null;
                    Socket socket = null;
                    AudioTrack audioTrack = null;
                    while (r_status) {
                        try {
                            if (socket == null) {
                                socket = new Socket();
                                InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.9", 8072);
                                try {
                                    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
                                    socket.connect(address, 6000);
                                    System.out.println("connecting-");
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    r_status = false;
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            is = socket.getInputStream();

                            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                            is.read(buffer);
                            if (audioTrack == null) {
                                audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 16000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffer.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                                audioTrack.play();
                            }

                            audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            r_status = false;
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    try {
                        is.reset();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        r_status = false;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            r_Thread.start();

        }


        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            Toasty.error(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, false).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkError() {

        }

        @Override
        public void getMenu(List tabsList) {
            MenuListAdapter menuListAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(tabsList);

            lstMenu.setAdapter(menuListAdapter);
        }

        private class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private List tabsList;

            public MenuListAdapter(List tabsList) {
                this.tabsList = tabsList;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return tabsList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public tabs getItem(int i) {
                return tabsList.get(i);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int i) {
                return tabsList.get(i).getId();
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lst_drawer_menu_item, null);
                }

                tabs tab = tabsList.get(i);

                TextBlock lblName = view.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
                ImageView imgIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

                try {
                    Resources resources = getResources();
                    final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("ic_title", "drawable", getPackageName());
                    Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(resourceId);

                    imgIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                lblName.setText(tab.getTitle());

                return view;
            }
        }
    }
```

and java server:

```
        package com.example.demo;

        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

        import javax.sound.sampled.*;
        import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.net.*;

        @SpringBootApplication
        public class DemoApplication {

            AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
            static AudioInputStream ais;
            static AudioFormat format;
            static boolean status = true;
            static int port = 50005;
            static int sampleRate = 44100;
            static ServerSocket serverSocket1;

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                receiveAudioFromAndroidClient();
                //streamToClientFromLocalFlie();
                SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
            }

            private static void receiveAudioFromAndroidClient() {
                try {
                    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
                    serverSocket1 = new ServerSocket(8072);


                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[4096];

                    format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);

                    while (status == true) {
                        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                            receiveData.length);

                        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                        ByteArrayInputStream baiss = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            receivePacket.getData());

                        ais = new AudioInputStream(baiss, format, receivePacket.getLength());

                    // A thread solve the problem of chunky audio
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                toSpeaker(receivePacket.getData());
                                streamToClient(receivePacket.getData());
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private static void streamToClient(byte[] data) {
                Thread test = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (serverSocket1.isBound()) {
                                Socket socket = serverSocket1.accept();


                                socket.getOutputStream().write(data);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                test.start();
            }

            private static void streamToClientFromLocalFlie() {
                try {
                    File soundFile = new File("E:\\Music\\Dariush\\Kisti.mp3");

                    try (ServerSocket serverSocker = new ServerSocket(8072);
                        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundFile)) {
                        if (serverSocker.isBound()) {
                            Socket client = serverSocker.accept();
                            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

                            byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];
                            int count;
                            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
                                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                     } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
                 try {
                     DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
                     SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);

                     sourceDataLine.open(format);

                    //FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                    //volumeControl.setValue(6.0206f);

                     sourceDataLine.start();
                     sourceDataLine.open(format);

                     sourceDataLine.start();

                    //System.out.println("format? :" + sourceDataLine.getFormat());

                    sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
                    System.out.println(soundbytes.toString());
                    sourceDataLine.drain();
                    sourceDataLine.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I send audio from android client and receive it in java server then play sound on server, but when I send audio from server to another android client on socket port, the sound is corrupted.

What would possibly be the problem in my code?

please help me

sorry for poor my english

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: sorry, i cann't find solution for this